# Mouseover for big devices and click for small devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a mouseover event for big devices, and for mobile or any other small devices I want to make it a click event (since mouseover is not working for mobile or iPad etc.). I have this jQuery code, but it seems to be not working. What is wrong with it?

```
if ($(window).width() < 991) {
    $('.open_products').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
    $('.open_cart').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebarcart').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay2').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
} else {
    $('.open_products').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
    $('.open_cart').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('#sidebarcart').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay2').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks to Robert for Edit

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add onresize for mobile devices, because its can be rotated.
- Better use window.matchMedia
- $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in') - must be without .in, because it can'd be found after first toogle.
- Use toggleClass and fadeToggle for mobile devices.
- Add mouseout for switch off active element.
- $(this).find for apply your styles only for element inside .open_products or .open_cart, in case it's nessesery.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        MyEvents();window.onresize=MyEvents;
    });
    function MyEvents(){
        if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:991px)").matches){
            $('.open_products').on('click', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay').fadeToggle();
                $(this).find('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=false]').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            });
            $('.open_cart').on('click', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebarcart').toggleClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay2').fadeToggle();
                $(this).find('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=false]').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            });
        } else {
            $('.open_products').on('mouseover', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn();
                $(this).find('.collapse').addClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
            $('.open_cart').on('mouseover', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebarcart').addClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay2').fadeIn();
                $(this).find('.collapse').addClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            });
            $('.open_products').on('mouseout', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut();
                $(this).find('.collapse').removeClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=false]').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            });
            $('.open_cart').on('mouseout', function () {
                $(this).find('#sidebarcart').removeClass('active');
                $(this).find('.overlay2').fadeOut();
                $(this).find('.collapse').removeClass('in');
                $(this).find('a[aria-expanded=false]').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason I can think of is: 
Is the code snippet you posted maybe executed before the buttons ('.open_cart', '.open_products') is rendered?

And, let me give you a hint: Try to avoid duplicate code. You could outsource the two event listeners in a function like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 991) {
    addProductAndCartEvtListeners();
} else {
    addProductAndCartEvtListeners();
}

function addProductAndCartEvtListeners() {
    $('.open_products').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
    $('.open_cart').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebarcart').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay2').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
}
```

Regarding you problem: If my first guess is not the solution, please provide more information in order for me to be able to help :)

Kind regards,

David

Comment: That doesn't help. Try to console.log() something when 1. the footer is rendered, and secondly console.log() when you add the event listeners. By that you see which code is executed first.